# convert &lt to < xml document

Tags: xml

I have read an XML file and converted into NSXMLDocument object. But, due to the presence of "<" in the string content of a node, it has been converted into "&lt". So, when i write it as xml document to a file, it has the character "&lt" in it.

How can i write to the file as ordinary XML file in which "&lt" will be replaced by "<".

Thanks and Regards,
Lenin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `<` character appears in a text node, it will be serialized as `&lt;` when you write your xml to a file.

When you later read that file with an xml parser, the text node will contain the original `<` character.

You also have the option of CDATA encoding the text node. In this case the serialized character is `<` inside a CDATA block. Many XML APIs will not retain any difference between CDATA and text nodes. CDATA should be thought of as an escaping mechanism to make editing easy for human authors.

Comment: In XML file (Java and DOM Parser), "&lt;" is present as node text value but when node.getContentType is used for this node then this is converted to "<". Is there anyway to retrieve "&lt;" itself, instead of  "<"?

Answer (score 1):

The `<` in text nodes of an xml should be represented as `&lt;`.

If you replace it using `s/&lt;/</g` before writing it to the xml file, it will lead to parsing error when you read from that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function for doing the vice versa operation

> htmlspecialchars and
>
> htmlentities()

Comment: Hi, my code is in cocoa. Can you give alternative methods to convert it in cocoa rather than htmlspecialchars and htmlentities()

Comment: @Lenin : Sorry , I am not aware of cocao

Answer (score 0):

The `<` character must be escaped when it's not part of an XML tag ([see here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/XML/xml_escape_chars.htm)). You really shouldn't break the XML spec...

However, if you must, you can perform a trick before writing your XML document:

1. Replace your instances of `<`
   with a unique string that won't be
   escaped by your XML parser (something that you know occurs nowhere else in the file).
   Something like `*-lt-*` will probably do.
2. Have the parser produce the file &
   save it.
3. Read in the file as
   plaintext, and replace your instances
   of `*-lt-*` with the regular `<`
   character.
4. Re-write the file,
   clobbering the version that was written by the XML parser.

Again, it's a terrible idea to break the XML spec... by doing this, no parser will be able to read your new XML document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace &lt to < in XML document via php:

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents("example.xml");

$xml= str_replace(['&lt;','&gt;'],['<','>'], $xmlFile);

echo $xml;
```

I am getting news feed from a server via XML and then store it to another xml file, I'm geting the result with `&lt;` and `&gt;` so I used this method. It's not a smartest way to store XML but I am not a pro mega senior back ender either.