# How to export CDATA from Excel spreadsheet to XML without escaping characters?

Tags: xml, excel, cdata

I'm trying to export data from Excel to an XML file. Everything works well except when I have CDATA elements in my Excel table. Excel is still escaping the < and > characters, for example. Any clue on how to export the CDATA ?

Example data from my Excel spreadsheet :

```
<![CDATA[ I don't want to escape < and > !]]>
```

How it looks like once exported in the XML file :

```
<blabla>&lt;![CDATA[ I don't want to escape &lt; and &gt; !]]&gt;</blabla>
```

What I would like to have in my XML file :

```
<blabla><![CDATA[ I don't want to escape < and > !]]></blabla>
```

Comment: How are you doing the export?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2399780/2521004) might help

Comment: I mapped my data to an XSD and I'm using the "export" under the developer tab (to export as an xml file).